# Is the double data type not suitable for my data / calculation?

Tags: c#, types

my unit test failed because of this, so I wonder if I am using the right datatype?

Reading the specs of the double I'd think it should be ok, but this is what's happening:

I'm reading a string from a file with value `0,0175` (comma as decimal sep.)

then I convert it to a double and then multiply it by 10000.

The function which does the multiply is this:

```
private static double? MultiplyBy10000(double? input)
        {
            if (!input.HasValue)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return input.Value*10000;
        }
```

next is from the immediate window:

```
input.Value
0.0175
input.Value*10000
175.00000000000003
```

And that is where my unit test fails, because I expect 175.

Is the double not accurate enough for this?

Checked other values too:

```
input.Value*1
0.0175
input.Value*10
0.17500000000000002
input.Value*100
1.7500000000000002
input.Value*1000
17.5
input.Value*10000
175.00000000000003
```

The weird thing is, I have 12 testcases 
0,0155
0,0225
0,016
0,0175
0,0095
0,016
0,016
0,0225
0,0235
0,0265

and assert 4 of these, and the other 3 don't have this behaviour

Comment: Double fractions are binary fractions. 0.5 in decimal is 0.1 in binary 0.25 is 0.01, etc. 0.0175 is apparently not exactly a binary fraction (or at least not with 64 bits in total)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is the double not accurate enough for this?

No, doubles are floating point numbers, which are [inaccurate by design](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c151dt3s.aspx). You can use `decimal` which is accurate and more suitable if you need exact numbers.

Comment: Thanks. That's a clear answer. Gonna change it.

Comment: All tests are green, thanks.

Comment: doubles are not inaccurate by design. decimals are not "more accurate" or "exact". The problem is you have too many fingers to be a good programmer. https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail/

Answer (score 1):

Floating point numbers where the value to the right of the decimal point are not powers of 2 cannot be accurately represented. Although you've got what looks like 0.0175 there's actually more data there.

After you've scaled the number up use [Math.Round](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to trim off date on the right off the decimal point.

Comment: Rounding might cause even more problems since it adds to the inaccuracy of the double.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - maybe. The downside to using a decimal though is that the performance isn't there.

Comment: And it occupies double the memory, but still, not a fan of rounding.